# Plotly Express - Change Existing Legend Lables

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to update the labels on the graph I am creating with plotly.

This is my current code. I have searched though the plotly tutorial but I cannot find a method of changing legend titles, when I have created the graph using first line.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/nicho/OneDrive - stevens.edu/Summer Research/Charts/Natural_Gas_Storage/Data/storage.csv", skiprows=4)

fig = px.line(df, x = "Week of", y=df.columns[1:], labels = {"variable":"Year"})
fig.update_xaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig.update_yaxes(title = "Billion Cubic Feet")
fig.update_layout(title = "Lower 48 Weekly Working Gas in Underground Storage")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `'Year'` column with better formatted data? This just removes what I thought was redundant info.

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].str.replace(' billion cubic feet', '').str.replace(' range', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the created legend directly updates the created graph settings. plotly figs are available in dictionary format and can be checked with `print(fig.data)`. My code uses the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#configuring-tick-labels) in the reference to change the name from ticker to generic name.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
names = ['Google','Apple','Amazon','FaceBook','Netflix','Microsoft']

fig = px.line(df, x="date", y=df.columns,
              hover_data={"date": "|%B %d, %Y"},
              title='custom tick labels')
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%b\n%Y")

for i,n in enumerate(names):
    fig.data[i].name = n
    
fig.layout.height=500

fig.show()
```

[image]

**Legend before modification**
[image]